# How to merge these two vhdl codes?

Tags: vhdl

We are trying to design a program that would add noise to the sinusoidal signal. We have designed code to generate sinusoidal signal, and have found code to  generate noise. We want to merge the two. Please check if the merging is correct on not.(We know that the code is not synthesizable as we are using real variables)

After we merge the code, the noise(DATA_OUTTT) is supposed to get added to the sinusoidal signal(data_out1 ) and result into (noisy_signal). How ever noise at each point is .something(ie. less than 1). Then why is the noise added signal(noisy_signal) showing values of noise more than 1 being added or subtracted?

Is it beacause this portion of the code has been added incorrectly?:

```
for i in 0 to nn-1 loop    -- nn noise generators
                   UNIFORM (s1(i),s2(i),r(i));
                   s:=s+r(i);
        end loop;
```

[image]

I am including all the three codes:

1) The Code for generating sinusoid:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.

entity sine_wave is
port (clk :in  std_logic;
      data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0)
      );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is
signal i : integer range 0 to 29:=0;
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=("01001101","01011101","01101100","01111010","10000111","10010000","10010111","10011010","10011010","10010111","10010000","10000111","01111010","01101100","01011101","01001101",
"00111101","00101110","00100000","00010011","00001010","00000011","00000000","00000000","00000011","00001010","00010011","00100000","00101110","00111101");
--hi
begin

process(clk)
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then     
data_out <= sine(i);
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 29) then
i <= 0;
end if;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

2)Code for generating noise:

```
library IEEE;
 use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
 use IEEE.math_real.all;
 entity Gauss_Gen is
  generic(nn:natural:=1; --power of the binomial distribution <16
  m:REAL:=0.0    -- mean output value
    );
   port(
    CLK : in STD_LOGIC;
    RST : in STD_LOGIC;
    DATA_OUT : out REAL:=0.0
    );
   end Gauss_Gen;
 architecture Model of Gauss_Gen is
        type arri is array (0 to 15) of integer;
        type arrr is array (0 to 15) of real;
 begin
 SFR:process(clk,rst)
  variable s1:arri:=(3,33,333,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,others=>55);
  variable s2:arri:=(5,55,555,50,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,21,33,others=>22);
  variable r:arrr:=(others=>0.0);
  variable s:real:=0.0;
        begin
           if rst='1' then
              DATA_OUT<=0.0;
           elsif  clk='1' and clk'event then
        s:=0.0;
        for i in 0 to nn-1 loop    -- nn noise generators
                   UNIFORM (s1(i),s2(i),r(i));
                   s:=s+r(i);
        end loop;
            DATA_OUT <= 2.0*(s/real(nn)-0.5)+ m;
           end if;
      end process;
  end Model;
```

3) The merged code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;  --try to use this library as much as possible.
 use IEEE.math_real.all;


entity sine_wave is

 generic(nn:natural:=1; --power of the binomial distribution <16
   m:REAL:=0.0     -- mean output value
     );

port (clk :in  std_logic;
      data_out : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
      DATA_OUTT : out REAL:=0.0
      );
end sine_wave;

architecture Behavioral of sine_wave is

type arri is array (0 to 15) of integer;
type arrr is array (0 to 15) of real;

signal data_out1 :  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
signal  noisy_signal,DATA_OUTTT : real;
signal i : integer range 0 to 29:=0;
--type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of integer;
type memory_type is array (0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0); 
--ROM for storing the sine values generated by MATLAB.
signal sine : memory_type :=("01001101","01011101","01101100","01111010","10000111","10010000","10010111","10011010","10011010","10010111","10010000","10000111","01111010","01101100","01011101","01001101",
"00111101","00101110","00100000","00010011","00001010","00000011","00000000","00000000","00000011","00001010","00010011","00100000","00101110","00111101");
--hi
begin

process(clk)
 variable s1:arri:=(3,33,333,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,22,33,others=>55);
 variable s2:arri:=(5,55,555,50,6,7,8,9,5,6,7,21,33,others=>22);
 variable r:arrr:=(others=>0.0);
 variable s:real:=0.0;
begin
  --to check the rising edge of the clock signal
if(rising_edge(clk)) then 

s:=0.0;
        for i in 0 to nn-1 loop    -- nn noise generators
                   UNIFORM (s1(i),s2(i),r(i));
                   s:=s+r(i);
        end loop;
            DATA_OUTT <= 2.0*(s/real(nn)-0.5)+ m;
            DATA_OUTTT <= 2.0*(s/real(nn)-0.5)+ m; 

data_out <= sine(i);
data_out1 <= sine(i);
noisy_signal<=real(to_integer(unsigned(data_out1)))+DATA_OUTTT;
i <= i+ 1;
if(i = 29) then
i <= 0;
end if;
end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: i had a look into the IEEE specification https://standards.ieee.org/downloads/1076/1076.2-1996/math_real.vhdl and was wondering, it says:  procedure UNIFORM(variable SEED1,SEED2:inout POSITIVE; variable X:out REAL); have you tried your noise generator before merging?
Without trying it looks like the uniform procedure has no output variable declared

Comment: Yes it seemed to generate uniform noise. nn=1 generates uniform noise and nn>=10 generates gaussian noise [see link](http://kanyevsky.kpi.ua/fpgadesign/dsp_rab1e.html)

Comment: @G.Kner : Sir, the output is DATA_OUT

Comment: What peak values of noise are you expecting, what values are you actually generating, and what is surprising you about the result?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Sir, if we look in the figure, data_out1 shows the value of the original sinusoidal signal which at some instant of time is 122. At that same instant, the value of noise is -0.65300995419421, which is given by DATA_OUTT. So,at that instant, we expect the noisy_signal to be 122+(-0.65300995419421)=121.346990046, but instead it is 135.591195087478.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954193/is-process-in-vhdl-reentrant/13956532#13956532 useful.

Answer (score 1):

You are making the assignment to `noisy_signal` inside the clocked process, which means that it doesn't take effect until the next clock edge. Note that the correct value appears in the next cycle.

If you want everything to occur in the same clock cycle, you need to move the assignment to `noisy_signal <= ...` *outside* the process.